# Dagger2 & nested child injections

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am fairly new to Dagger2. Lets say I have the following structure:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         DependencyInjector.applicationComponent.inject(this);
    }
    ...

    public void foo() {
        B b = new B();
        **DependencyInjector.applicationComponent.inject(b);**
    }
}

public class B {
    @Inject
    C c;
}
```

My question is, do I have to explicitly inject "b", all though "A" is already injected?! Or is it enough to inject "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in that example, you have to explicitly inject B, as you do for everything that comes from a call to `new`. Dagger can't interfere with that call.

However, by deferring to an injected, Dagger-created `Provider`, you can take advantage of A's injection so you don't have to inject B:

```
public class A extends Activity {
    @Inject Provider<B> bProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         DependencyInjector.applicationComponent.inject(this);
    }
    ...

    public void foo() {
        B b = bProvider.get();  // This instance will be fully injected.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. And what would be the better way?!

Comment: The way I have it in my code sample is the "better way", in that it's better to let Dagger be responsible for the creation of your injectable objects. Save your use of `inject` methods for objects that Android or other frameworks create for you, like your Activity subclass here. You can still use `new` for simple objects like model objects that don't need to participate in your object graph; see [a discussion of "injectables" versus "newables" here](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/).

Comment: And "c" will be injected as well?!

Comment: Yes, and any `@Inject` fields within `c`, and so forth all the way through your graph.